# How do I restore the relationship between two tables after moving data to another table?

Tags: mysql

The tables `accounts` and `contacts` have a many-to-many relationship, for this there is the table `accounts_contacts` with the fields `account_id` and `contact_id`.

[image]

The table `account` has the field `type` where one of its possible values is `brand`.

I have created a new table called `brand` where I migrate the records of `accounts` where the type is `brand`. This new table also has a many-to-many relationship with `contacts`. The above works fine.

[image]

I must now create or reestablish the relationships between `brand` and `contacts` in a new table called `brands_contatcs` equal to the one that existed between `accounts` and `contacts`

Could you give me an indication how to do this. Thanks in advance

Comment: You could potentially create an extra column in `brand` to store the original `account_id`, use this join brand to account_contact and populate the `brand_contact` table,then once done drop the `account_id` column from `brand` then delete records from `account_contact` then `account` where they have migrated to brand. Or if you already have another unique within `account` that also exists in `brand` then simply use this.

Comment: Does this definitely need to be a new table though? If brand is a subset of account then you just create a view that is `CREATE VIEW Brand AS SELECT <SomeColumns> FROM account WHERE type = 'Brand'`, and do the same for `brand_contact`. Or if `brand` extends account you could just retain the account record and make `account_id` a primary key and a foreign key in `brand` to store any additional information this type requires (i.e. [table inheritance](https://www.sqlteam.com/articles/implementing-table-inheritance-in-sql-server))

Comment: The id of the records in the `brand` table are the same ids they had in `accounts`. About creating a new table, it has been requested by the client and due to certain particularities of the development platform I have had to create a new table

Comment: It makes sense if I get the records from the `account_contacts` table where the `account` `type` is `brand` and then in the `brand_contacts` table I import this data. The above, because the ids of the records in `brand` match the ids that were in `accounts`?

`select ac.* from accounts_contacts ac inner join accounts a on a.id = ac.account_id where a.account_type = 'brand' and a.deleted = false;`

Comment: You shouldn't even need to do that, if the ids are the same you can just join to the brand table directly. [Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/f9qBfOH3)